# Understanding the dimensions of states returned by rnn.BasicLSTMCell

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am watching this tutorial where he write a tensorflow code for the MNIST classification.
Here is the RNN model:

```
batch_size = 128
chunk_size = 28
n_chunks = 28
rnn_size = 128

def recurrent_neural_network(x):
   layer = {'weights':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([rnn_size,n_classes])),
         'biases':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_classes]))}

   x = tf.transpose(x, [1,0,2])
   x = tf.reshape(x, [-1, chunk_size])
   x = tf.split(x, n_chunks, 0)

   lstm_cell = rnn.BasicLSTMCell(rnn_size,state_is_tuple=True)
   outputs, states = rnn.static_rnn(lstm_cell, x, dtype=tf.float32)

   output = tf.matmul(outputs[-1],layer['weights']) + layer['biases']

   return output,outputs,states
```

after this i print out the dimensions of outputs and states respectively
like this:

```
print("\n", len(outputs),"\n",len(outputs[0]),"\n",len(outputs[0][0]))
print("\n", len(states),"\n",len(states[0]),"\n",len(states[0][0]))
```

I get the output of print statements as:
28
128
128

2
128
128

I understand that the output shape is 28x128x128 (time_steps x rnn_size x batch_size)
but i don't understand the shape of "states" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this very good blog post about how LSTMs work : http://colah.github.io/posts/2015-08-Understanding-LSTMs/

LSTMs have one hidden state but also one memory cell state; hence the size of the first dimension of your `states` variable (2). The size of the following dimensions are `batch_size` then `rnn_size`.

Comment: So for every chunk (28 numbers) in the batch_size(128 such chunks), the LSTM will change it's internal state?
And do you know any source that explains batch processing in rnn?
Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 1):

The `states` contains 2 matrix, `cell` and `hidden` which is `c` and `h` in following formula.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Each LSTM have two states, 0th for Long term state, whereas 1st for short term state. 
*BasicRNNCell, always have one state, i.e. short term state.*

Rest you already explained:

**128**: Number of Neurons or can say rnn_size in your case.

**128**: Batch size i.e. one output for each input.